# How to iterate over all ways of choosing n b-bit arrays from all possible b-bit arrays?

Tags: julia, combinatorics

There are `2^b` b-bit arrays. There are "`2^b` choose `n`" different ways of choosing `n` b-bit arrays. I would like to iterate over all  "`2^b` choose `n`" different ways of choosing `n` b-bit arrays.  Clearly this is only possible in a realistic time frame if `b` and `n` are both small.

How could I do that in Julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `combinations` from [Combinatorics.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Combinatorics.jl) to generate the various combinations. And, depending on what you're looking for, you can use either `string` or `bitstring` to convert integers into their binary representation:

```
julia> string(123, base=2)
"1111011"

julia> bitstring(123)
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111011"
```

For brevity, I will stick with `string`. Here's an example of the full calculation for the case of `b = 3` and `n = 2`:

```
julia> using Combinatorics

julia> r = 0:2^3-1
0:7

julia> b = string.(r, base=2)
8-element Array{String,1}:
 "0"  
 "1"  
 "10" 
 "11" 
 "100"
 "101"
 "110"
 "111"

julia> combs = combinations(b, 2);

julia> foreach(println, combs)
["0", "1"]
["0", "10"]
["0", "11"]
["0", "100"]
["0", "101"]
["0", "110"]
["0", "111"]
["1", "10"]
["1", "11"]
["1", "100"]
["1", "101"]
["1", "110"]
["1", "111"]
["10", "11"]
["10", "100"]
["10", "101"]
["10", "110"]
["10", "111"]
["11", "100"]
["11", "101"]
["11", "110"]
["11", "111"]
["100", "101"]
["100", "110"]
["100", "111"]
["101", "110"]
["101", "111"]
["110", "111"]
```